# Freezing when added to linked list (C)

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

My code compiles correctly, but when I execute, the insertLast is called twice and then my program freezes. I can't see why it would work twice but then freeze up.

The code to send the nodes to my linked list:

```
int main ()
    {
    LinkedList* canQueue=createList();

    for(ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++)
        {
        TinCan* tempCan = (TinCan*) malloc(sizeof(TinCan));
        insertLast(canQueue, tempCan);
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

And the linked list methods I used:

```
LinkedList* createList() /*creates empty linked list*/
    {
        LinkedList* myList;
        myList = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
        myList->head = NULL;
        return myList;
    }



void insertLast(LinkedList* list, TinCan *newData)
    {
    int ii = 1;
    LinkedListNode* newNode = (LinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));
    newNode->data = newData;
    newNode->next = NULL;

        if(list->head == NULL)
            {
        list->head = newNode;
        newNode->next=NULL;
        }
    else
        {
        LinkedListNode* current = list->head;
        while (current->next != NULL)
            {
            current = current->next;
            }
        current->next = newNode;
        ii++;

        }
}
```

Comment: There is something odd, you do not declare `ii` in main and you have a local `ii` in `insertLast` that does not seem to be doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of looks like you are setting the first node to be it's own neighbour. Note that you are working with pointers and they do not necessarily copy the underlying object.

```
    list->head = newNode;
    newNode->next=NULL;
    current = list->head;
    current->next = newNode;
```

at the start you have head as newnode then current as head (current  = newnode) then current.next = newnode (newnode.next = newnode). Because you are in a while loop you will loop through this one node forever until you exit the program.

Comment: Thanks I see the problem now